# Нужно сделать график с заливкой

Tags: python, график

Нужно построить график с заливкой, область положительных значений одним цветом, отрицательных другим.
У меня есть текстовый файл. В нем значения для оси
x:
1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0
y:
-6.8, -6.8, -22.6, -8.3, -5.6, 1.7, -2.2, -4.9, 0.6, 0.4, -5.2, -20.8, -22.0, -10.8,  -4.1,  -3.2,  -2.0,  -0.4, -20.5, -16.5, -18.6, -11.2, -15.1, -15.0, -8.1, 2.3, 4.4

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

file = open("d2.txt", "r")
data = [map(float, line.split("\t")) for line in file]

x = np.asarray(x)
y = np.asarray(y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.fill_between(x, y, where=y > 0, color="red")
ax.fill_between(x, y, where=y < 0, color="blue")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

В итоге выходит ошибка.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Obi_wan\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\pythonProject2\Diag.py", line 7, in <module>
    x = np.asarray(x)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Недавно начал изучать Python и не всё пока понимаю, можете объяснить что я делаю не так?

Переделал:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
file = open("d2.txt", "r")
x, y = [map(float, line.split("\t")) for line in file]

x = np.asarray(x)
y = np.asarray(y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.fill_between(x, y, where=y > 0, color="red")
ax.fill_between(x, y, where=y < 0, color="blue")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Теперь вылезает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Obi_wan\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\pythonProject2\DD.py", line 10, in <module>
    ax.fill_between(x, y, where=y > 0, color="red")
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'map' and 'int'
```

Comment: Непонятно, зачем вам `numpy` вообще. Ну, наверное, достаточно так: `x, y = data` после строки `data = ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` вы всё-равно не используете, так что можете вместо

```
data = [map(float, line.split("\t")) for line in file]
```

Написать:

```
x, y = [list(map(float, line.split(","))) for line in file]
```

Если у вас вдруг больше строк в файле чем нужно и будет ругаться, что некуда девать лишние данные, то можно попробовать так:

```
x, y, *_ = [list(map(float, line.split(","))) for line in file]
```

Но это всё на случай, если у вас вообще правильный формат файла разбирается, в чём я совсем не уверен.

Comment: С этим понял, но теперь вылезает другое. 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Obi_wan\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\pythonProject2\DD.py", line 7, in <module>
    ax.fill_between(x, y, where=y > 0, color="red")
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'map' and 'int'

Comment: А, похоже `map` надо ещё в `list` обернуть, я изменил код, показал как

Comment: Там график всё-равно фигня какая-то получается, с этим ещё нужно разбираться )

Comment: Да, это просмотрел, дал не те данные на X, поправил. 

Сделал к у вас код, с добавлением list.
Не хочет работать, пишет ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0\n'

Comment: Ага, ну тогда надо `split(',')` делать, а не по табуляции, как у вас в коде

Comment: честно, ничего не понял :)
Я до этого split использовал только чтобы предложения на слова разбить, в обучении, куда его тут засунуть, если не затруднит,что в коде поменять?

Comment: Так я уже поменял код в своём ответе )  `\t` - это табуляция, у вас не табуляцией, а запятой данные разделены